# c# foreach image in folder

Tags: c#, image, foreach, tessnet2, magicknet

Below is some code that

1. creates a directory
2. uses MagickNet to covert a PDF into separate BMP images and stores it in a folder (ImagePath)
3. Then it uses TessNet2 to scan each image in that folder to parse out information

I can't seem to get the foreach loop that scans the ImagePath folder. Any help?

The error right now is on the 'foreach' statement and it says "Cannot convert type 'char' to 'System.Drawing.Image'"

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ImagePath = exePath + "\\Images"; 
        if (!Directory.Exists(ImagePath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(ImagePath);
        }

        MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
        settings.Density = new MagickGeometry(300, 300);

        using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
        {
            images.Read(@"D:\Test\ABStest.pdf",settings);
            int page = 1;
            foreach (MagickImage image in images)
            {
                image.Write(ImagePath + "\\ABS" + page + ".bmp");
                page++;
            }
        }



        foreach (Image item in ImagePath)
        {
            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(item))
            {
                tessnet2.Tesseract tessocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
                tessocr.Init(@"C:\Users\Matt Taylor\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TessNet2\TessNet2\bin\Debug\tessdata", "eng", false);
                tessocr.GetThresholdedImage(bmp, Rectangle.Empty).Save("c:\\temp\\" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".bmp");
                // Tessdata directory must be in the directory than this exe
                Console.WriteLine("Multithread version");
                ocr.DoOCRMultiThred(bmp, "eng");
                //Console.WriteLine("Normal version");
                //ocr.DoOCRNormal(bmp, "eng");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to save the file to disk. You could use the .ToBitmap() method of MagickImage.

```
foreach (MagickImage image in images)
{
  using (Bitmap bmp = image.ToBitmap())
  {
    tessnet2.Tesseract tessocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
    // etc...
  }
}
```

Comment: I had no clue about that method. Works perfectly and makes it so I don't have to waste space creating images. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Directory.GetFiles` to return all the filenames in the directory and create your `Bitmaps` from there

```
foreach (string imageFileName in Directory.GetFiles(ImagePath))
{
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imageFileName))
    {
    }
}
```

But if there are other files in that folder you should add a filter

```
foreach (string imageFileName in Directory.GetFiles(ImagePath, "*.jpg"))
{
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imageFileName))
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I missed that MaylorTaylor wanted a Bitmap after loading the Image.  The filter is a good thought too.

Comment: Said this about 2 hours ago :) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17930913/1324033)

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through `String ImagePath`, which gives you a collection of characters.  You need to search through the directory with `Directory.GetFiles()`, and load the images with `Image.FromFile()`:

```
foreach (String itemPath in Directory.GetFiles(ImagePath))
{
    using (Image item = Image.FromFile(itemPath))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```