# Foreach bitmap in folder

Tags: c#, foreach, bitmap, directory

So below is some code that uses TessNet's OCR tool to scans each bitmap in the folder and processes the OCR information into `List<tessnet2.Word> result`. But I can't seem to get the foreach to work right.
 I get the following error `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo' because 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

```
     DirectoryInfo diBMP = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\temp\\bmps");

                            foreach (Bitmap bmp in diBMP)
                            {                                         
                              using (tessnet2.Tesseract tessocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract())
                                    {                                        

                                        tessocr.Init(@"C:\Users\Matt Taylor\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TessNet2\TessNet2\bin\Debug\tessdata", "eng", false);

                                        tessocr.GetThresholdedImage(bmp, System.Drawing.Rectangle.Empty).Save("c:\\temp\\" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".bmp");


                                        Console.WriteLine("Normal version");
                                        List<tessnet2.Word> result = ocr.DoOCRNormal(bmp, "eng");

                                        CheckANDCorrectPDForientation(result, pdfFiles);                                                                             
                                    }                                    
                            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want

```
foreach(string s in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.bmp"))
{
    using(Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(s))
    {
      //code here
     }
 }
```

Your error is because a foreach loop must have something to loop through, `DirectoryInfo` will just give you information about the directory